# JQuery questionnaire that returns results

Tags: php, jquery

I am brand new to this part of coding but I wanted to know if anyone can possibly direct me to any code that I can use to build a questionnaire that will return a set value for example.

If I want to tell men over 50 to get a colonoscopy my form will say:

1. select one  (Male /female)
2. Age select one (0-10 10-20 20-40 40 and up)

If the person selects male and 40 and up the return value will be, "colonoscopy suggested" or whatever text i set for that age group.

Thanks

Comment: Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/8Lcq62mn/16/

Comment: why is this tagged mysqli?

Comment: @Max and y jQuery, or php?@CRN u may use [limesurvey](https://www.limesurvey.org/en/)

Comment: @Trix,  what about a peronality survey that returns values based on the answers that are chosen? something like that. Please advise.

Comment: You can invest some time and write one. What do u mean by advice? Thats something about hunderds of lines of code

Comment: @trix did i mention im new to this?